# Highcharts Gantt avoid overlapping tasks

Tags: highcharts

I reviewed the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624319/highchart-gantt-chart-no-overlapping) which raises a number of follow up questions on generalizing the solution to support a variable number of rows per category, now that I have my code in place to split the various tasks into the required rows.

I have used the original fiddle and modified it, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpic80/70g4vhfx/) to better understand the concept.

```
    var today = new Date(),
  day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();


// THE CHART
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
        var chart = this,
        series = chart.series[0];

        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          point.graphic.translate(0, -50);
        });

        series = chart.series[1];

        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          point.graphic.translate(0, -50);
       });

        series = chart.series[2];

        series.points.forEach(function(point) {
          point.graphic.translate(0, -50);
       });
}
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Grouping tasks vertically'
  },
  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Resource 1', 'Resource 2', 'Resource 3'],
    breaks: [{
        breakSize: 1,
      from: 0,
      to: 0
    },{
        breakSize: 1,
      from: 1,
      to: 1
    },{
        breakSize: 1,
      from: 2,
      to: 2
    }]
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Resource 1',
    data: [{
      name: 'Task A',
      y: 0,
      start: today - (2 * day),
      end: today + (6 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task B',
      y: 0.5,
      start: today - (1 * day),
      end: today + (6 * day),
      color: 'rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.7)'
    }, {
      name: 'Task C',
      y: 0.99,
      start: today + (1 * day),
      end: today + (17 * day),
      color: 'rgba(80, 180, 180, 0.7)'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Resource 2',
    data: [{
      name: 'Task D',
      y: 1,
      start: today - (1 * day),
      end: today + (6 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task E',
      y: 1.6,
      start: today + (7 * day),
      end: today + (9 * day),
      color: 'rgba(230, 180, 180, 0.7)'
    }, {
      name: 'Task F',
      y: 1,
      start: today + (11 * day),
      end: today + (12 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task G',
      y: 1,
      start: today + (14 * day),
      end: today + (16 * day)
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Resource 3',
    data: [{
      name: 'Task H',
      y: 2,
      start: today - (1.5 * day),
      end: today + (4 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task I',
      y: 2,
      start: today + (6 * day),
      end: today + (9 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task J',
      y: 2,
      start: today + (10 * day),
      end: today + (14 * day)
    }, {
      name: 'Task K',
      y: 2.5,
      start: today + (15 * day),
      end: today + (17 * day),
      color: 'rgba(230, 180, 180, 0.7)'
    }]
  }]
});
```

I can see that we have a number a pieces that must work together. We first seem to require a break for each category that will have multiple rows, we need to set the "y" attribute to a decimal portion of the category offset and we need to apply the translate on the category series.

What is unclear is how the values for breakSize, translate offset and "y" are arrived at.

Next this is now using a series per category, while we can generate charts with a single series, like a tree grid, so are we required here to break the data into individual series? We offer our user the ability to control series to match with legend control, so that might be a challenge.

I noticed that you added a color and when I didn't most often I would not see my range, why would it be necessary?

Lastly, you will notice that in my fiddle, there is an extra category named "3" that is showing up. Looked at the json coming in to the ganttchart method and after the basic transform and I see no hint of where this can come from?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that this is only a workaround and this is not implemented functionality, which could not work in some cases, like see on the tooltip in your example - it is not anchored properly (because the point was translated).

> What is unclear is how the values for breakSize, translate offset and "y" are arrived at.

For me, it seems like this behaviour was unexpected. The documentation says that:

> A number indicating how much space should be left between the start and the end of the break. The break size is given in axis units, so for instance on a datetime axis, a break size of 3600000 would indicate the equivalent of an hour.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks

There is no information about making the y axis row higher, but it seems like breakSize set to 1 makes the yAxis row height doubled.

> Next this is now using a series per category, while we can generate charts with a single series, like a tree grid, so are we required here to break the data into individual series? We offer our user the ability to control series to match with legend control, so that might be a challenge.

Here I am not 100% sure what you had in mind. I assumed that you would like to create something like you have asked about here: [HighCharts gantt treegrid collapse details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742440/highcharts-gantt-treegrid-collapse-details/59749432?noredirect=1#comment105647122_59749432) but implementing this functionality will require some changes in the core code.

> I noticed that you added a color and when I didn't most often I would not see my range, why would it be necessary?

I found that points in the gantt inherit colors from the yAxis value which they are assigned to.

For example: the first point is assigned to the 0 value in the yAxis, that makes that this point has class set to **highcharts-point highcharts-color-0**, next while rendering the points, function checks which class is assigned and fills this color from the default Highcharts color array on that point. So if point has y set to 0.5, it wouldn't work.

API to colors array: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors

> Lastly, you will notice that in my fiddle, there is an extra category named "3" that is showing up. Looked at the json coming in to the ganttchart method and after the basic transform and I see no hint of where this can come from?

This '3' shows up because you had defined only 3 categories, meanwhile you set the y value for the last point to 2.5, which is higher than the range of assigned categories.

To sum up - this feature is not implemented yet and what you are trying to do is much more than regular API options offers.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, helps clarify a number of things but still leave me without a real solution, will have to experiment. As for the series, we used them to group data, like in the official example of project 1, project 2, etc and the user can control via legend. So if series are needed to manage overlap layout, it breaks other functionality.

Comment: As I said before - your requirement is a custom functionality which is not implemented yet in Highcharts Gantt. You can share your idea on the Highcharts userVoice channel (where sometimes core developers suggest some temporary solutions) https://highcharts.uservoice.com/ or contact https://www.blacklabel.pl/. I found related topic: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12109 have you seen this? Maybe this kind of solution will be useful for you.

Comment: The other topic might be a bit related but here my main concern to is support multiple rows per category to avoid overlapping, while the example shows disjoined tasks. Then the collapse tree grid should work correctly as well.